# how to dock bottem devtools using Command Line

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

There is any flag which can dock bottom chrome devtools ?? I wanna use with add_argument in the chromeDiver Selenium to change the defaut dock side of the devtools automatically

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: I use devtools to produce HAR, chrome_profile.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs") but i need the devtools to be in the bottom not in the left ( the default dock side)